# flatMap in scala, the compiler says it's wrong

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file which contains lines which contain items separated by ","
for example:

```
2 1,3
3 2,5,7
5 4
```

Now I want to flatMap this file to such rdd:

```
2 1
2 3
3 2
3 5
5 7
5 4
```

I wonder how to realize this function in scala:

```
  val pairs = lines.flatMap { line =>
        val a = line.split(" ")(0)
        val partb = line.split(" ")(1)
        for (b <- partb.split(",")) {
          yield a + " " + b
        }
      }
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying your code example. In your case, the only problem is the location of your `yield` keyword. Move it to before the curly braces, like so:

```
for (b <- partb.split(",")) yield {
  a + " " + b
}
```

Comment: no, this is just a simple example, if I want to add other complex logic, this does not work.

Comment: @user2848932 You're welcome! If my answer was helpful, please upvote it or make it the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `yield` THEN the return logic

```
yield {a}
```

The way you are doing it now is a `for loop`, not a `for comprehension`, which will yell about the `yield` keyword, and even if not it would return a `Unit`

```
val pairs = lines.flatMap { line =>
    for (a <- line.split(",")) yield {
      a
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the relocation of yield for delivering a collection, as already exposed, consider this possible refactoring where we extract the first two entries from `split`,

```
 val pairs = lines.flatMap { line =>
        val Array(a, partb, _*) = line.split(" ")
        for (b <- partb.split(",")) 
          yield a + " " + b
      }
```

and yet more concise is

```
val pairs = lines.flatMap { line => 
  val Array(a,tail) = line.split(" |,", 2)
  for (t <- tail) yield s"$a $t"
}
```

where we split by either " " or "," and extract the head and the tail, then we apply string interpolation to produce the desired result.